# Cannot create only IAM policy with cloudformation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I am having issue with creating IAM policy in cloudformation.But when I run it I get the error that Groups,Roles,Users is required:

Here is my code:

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion": "2010-09-09",
"Description": "AWS CloudFormation Template IAM Groups and Policies",
"Resources": {
    "PolicyAutoScalingLimitedOperation": {
        "Type": "AWS::IAM::Policy",
        "Properties": {
            "PolicyName": "AutoScaling-Limited-Operation",
            "PolicyDocument": {
                "Statement": [{
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "dynamodb:*"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "cloudwatch:PutMetricData"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "xray:PutTraceSegments",
                            "xray:PutTelemetryRecords"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "s3:Get*",
                            "s3:List*",
                            "s3:PutObject"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "logs:PutLogEvents",
                            "logs:CreateLogStream"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:*:*:log-group:/aws/elasticbeanstalk*"
                    },
                    {
                        "Effect": "Allow",
                        "Action": [
                            "kms:ListAliases",
                            "kms:ListKeys",
                            "kms:Encrypt",
                            "kms:Decrypt"
                        ],
                        "Resource": "*"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now when I run it I get:

```
At least one of [Groups,Roles,Users] must be non-empty.
```

Does that mean I cannot create policy with cloudformation without adding user/role to it?

Comment: The documentation states that the AWS::IAM::Policy resource does not simply create a policy. It associates a policy with an existing IAM group, role or user (as indicated here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-policy.html).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You probably want to create an `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy` if you just want a standalone policy.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html

Answer (score 11):

From the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html):

> AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy creates an AWS Identity and Access Management
>   (IAM) managed policy for your AWS account, which you can use to apply
>   permissions to IAM users, groups, and roles.

Here's an example:

```
Resources:
  CreateTestDBPolicy: 
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties: 
      Description: "Policy for creating a test database"
      Path: "/"
      PolicyDocument: 
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement: 
        - 
          Effect: "Allow"
          Action: "rds:CreateDBInstance"
          Resource: "*"
```

This will resolve your issue.